# Initiate new generic class object with reflection and new()

Tags: c#, .net, new-operator, generic-programming, generic-collections

While I was working on repository design using generic type, I was trying to initiate a new class object, however, since in the generic class, I have no idea what property my concrete class object might have, I was thinking if there is any way to use Reflection at run time, so that .Net would check on which properties my class object have, and assign value to it dynamically, here is an example and what I am stuck with

```
    public abstract class AdoRepository<TEntity> : IAdoRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        private readonly string _connection;
        public AdoRepository(string connection)
        {
            _connection = connection;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllWithStoredProcedureAsync(string storedProcedureName, List<SqlParameter> lstParam)
        {
            DataTable dt = await SqlDataHelper.ExecuteDataTableAsync(_connection, storedProcedureName, lstParam);

            return (from row in dt.Select()
                    select new TEntity()
                    {
                        // Question: anyway to use reflection here so that like
                        // Below is what I am trying to do but not be able to
                        foreach (Property p in TEntity.Properties) {
                             switch p.DataType
                                 case 'Int32':
                                      p.Value = Convert.ToInt32(row[p.Name].ToString());
                                      break;
                                 case 'System.String':
                                      p.Value = row[p.Name].ToString();
                                      break;
                                 ....
                                 default:
                                      p.Value = row[p.Name].ToString();
                                      break;
                        }
                    }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: whats the error ? and where is it failing

Comment: Please elaborate what are you trying to implement that modern ORMs do not have? It is always to fun to make something interesting, but I consider there is already working solution for what you are trying to do.

Comment: So what I am trying to do is using ADO.Net with Repository pattern, however I didn't find any available solution online that could using generic pattern with reflection...